# Save and load state of tf.random

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, random

I have a Tensorflow model that utilises dropout, which is controlled by the state of `tf.random`. At the start of my code, I set the global seed using `tf.set_seed(DEFAULT_SEED)`.
As training progresses, I want to be able to save the state of `tf.random`, so that if I want to stop and then resume training, I can load that state and training can continue from where it left off. For example, `np.random` has methods `set_state()` and `get_state()`, however I can't find an equivalent for tf.random. Am I missing something or is this not doable?

Numpy example:

```
np.random.set_seed(1234)

for i in range(10):
    print(np.random.randn())

x = np.random.get_state()
np.random.set_state(x)
```

and the state is the same as where we left it.

Comment: I believe you are looking for https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint   Generators can be freely saved and restored using tf.train.Checkpoint. The checkpoint can be restored in a distribution strategy with a different number of replicas than the original strategy. If a replica ID is present in both the original and the new distribution strategy, its state will be properly restored (i.e. the random-number stream from the restored point will be the same as that from the saving point)

Comment: Would [get_global_generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/get_global_generator) and [set_global_generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_global_generator) meet your requirements?